# Flutter: Push notification action buttons works locally but not on the playstore

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I'm coming to you because, since I put the "qr_code_scanner" package on my Flutter application, I no longer receive the actions buttons in the push notifications when I put my app in test on PlayStore and TestFlight. When I test on the Android Studio emulator, I get the notification with the 2 action buttons, but as soon as I put it on the Store, there's nothing. I think it might be a version problem, but I don't know any more.

Flutter: 3.7.8
Dart: 2.19.5

```html
name: app
description: App
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  two_fa_plugin:
    path: ../

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  http: ^0.13.6
  intl: 0.17.0
  crypto: ^3.0.3
  async: ^2.4.1
  provider: ^6.0.5
  flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
  device_info: ^2.0.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0
  circular_countdown_timer: ^0.2.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  flutter_translate: ^4.0.3
  flash: ^1.3.1
  back_button_interceptor: ^6.0.2
  local_auth: ^1.1.8
  move_to_background: 1.0.2
  upgrader: ^6.5.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.0
  dio: ^5.1.2
  sticky_headers: 0.3.0+2
  in_app_update: 4.0.1
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  cryptography: ^2.5.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/i18n/
```

I tried to update the packages but I still have the problem

Comment: Try to run the application on a real device with debug mode and check all the logs. Probably you will find something there.

Comment: In debug mode, I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to review the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion according to the packages you are using.

Comment: is it possible that the playstore has blocked custom push notification plugins?